# JPA 2.0 @AttributeOverride ignored with @Embedded

Tags: jpa

I have the following scenario:

Person person
|-- Address myAddress
|-- Address secondaryAddress

where:
Address
|-- Zip myZip
|-- Zip mySecondaryZip
|-- String name

Zip
|-- Country myCountry
|-- String zipCode

Country
|-- String description;

Address, Zip and Country classes are declared @Embeddable(). Person is an @Entity.

myAddress has the following JPA annotations:

```
    @Embedded()
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(column = @Column(name = "myaddress_name"), name = "name"),
        @AttributeOverride(column = @Column(name = "myaddress_myzip_zipcode"), name = "myZip.zipCode"),
        @AttributeOverride(column = @Column(name = "myaddress_myzip_mycountry_description"), name = "myZip.myCountry.description"),
        @AttributeOverride(column = @Column(name = "myaddress_mysecondaryzip_zipcode"), name = "mySecondaryZip.zipCode"),
        @AttributeOverride(column = @Column(name = "myaddress_mysecondaryzip_mycountry_description"), name = "mySecondaryZip.myCountry.description") })
private Address myAddress = null;
```

Using eclipseLink and postgresql as db the columns:

myaddress_myzip_zipcode
myaddress_myzip_mycountry_description

are not created in person table. The others are correctly created.
We are using JPA 2.0 and postgresql 9.2. Why does it happen ? Am I missing something obvious ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be having an issue with the 3 levels of nesting.

Ty the latest release, and if still not working log a bug.